# Table invisible in PostgreSQL - Undefined relation issue at different sessions

Tags: postgresql, create-table

I have executed the following create statement using SQLWorkbench at my target postgresql database:

```
  CREATE TABLE Config (    
  id serial  PRIMARY KEY,       
  pub_ip_range_low  varchar(100),       
  pub_ip_range_high varchar(100)            
  );
```

Right after table creation I request the table content by typing 'select * from config;' and see that table could be retrieved. Nevertheless, my java program that uses JDBC type 4 driver cannot access the table when I issue the same select statement in it. An exception is thrown when the program tries to access it which says says "Undefined relation" for the config table.

My questions are:

1. Why sqlworkbench where I had previously run the create statement recognizes the table while my java program cannot find it?
2. Where does the postgressql DBMS puts the tables I created? I don't see them neither in public nor in information schema.

NOTE:
I checked target postgres database and cannot see the table Config anywhere although SQL workbench can query it. Then I opened another SQL workbench instance and noticed that the table cannot be queried (i.e. not found). So, my conclusion is that PostgreSQL puts the table I created in the first running SQLBench instance into some location that is bound to that session. Another SQL Workbench instance or my java program is not bound to session, so cannot query the previously created table config.

Comment: Try to run `SELECT current_schema()` inside SQLWorkbench to check in which schema are you creating the table. Try also in java to check which schema are you querying. Have you got any transactions open?

Comment: Try to avoid mixed case identifiers. They might lead to confusion.

Comment: The above select statement return public. I tried to query the table from my java program by typing public.config but did not help me solve the problem at all. Thanks anyway/Any more suggestion?

Comment: Trouble-shooting guide: 1 check/monitor the logfile. 2) eliminate the middleman: connect to the db via psql or pgadmin[3].

Comment: Did you check the permissions? Make sure the user you connect with can access the schema (should be schema `public` by default) and the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the create failed on the extra trailing comma?

```
 CREATE TABLE config (
  id serial  PRIMARY KEY,       
  pub_ip_range_low  varchar(100),       
  pub_ip_range_high varchar(100)   -- >> ,           
  );
```

Comment: `Right after table creation I request the table content by typing 'select * from config;' and see that table could be retrieved.` So, probably not.

Comment: I had to delete some company specific field names from the create statement when I was pasting it to here so apparently a comma remained from the delete of these field names but the orginal create statement is fine and executed successfully.

Comment: It was just a wild guess, since your problem seems a bit spooky. BTW some of us (including Erwin and myself) have the habit of putting the commas at the beginnings of the lines. That makes them more visible, and it makes editing a bit easier.

Answer (score 2):

The only "bloody location" that is session-local in PostgreSQL is the schema `pg_temp`, in other words: temporary tables. But your `CREATE` command does not display the keyword `TEMP[ORARY]`. Of course, as long as the *transaction* is not *commited*, nobody sees anything outside the transaction.

It's more likely you are seeing a switcheroo of hosts / databases / ports / or the schema `search_path`. A mixup with the mixed-case table name is a hot candidate, too. If you don't double-quote `"Config"`, the table ends up all lower case in the system, so: `config`. If you later double quote the name, it won't match. [The manual has the details](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: I issues a commit after the create database command but did not help. I query the database at lowercase in both SQL workbench and my Java program. Thanks.